# How to integrate with google authenticator codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-authenticator

I want to integrate my login system with google authenticator using codeigniter framework.

How to do it?

Comment: This is not the right kind of question for StackOverlfow

Comment: Okay, sorry - i will remember it. :)

Comment: I would ask on http://forum.codeigniter.com/